# Подключение к MySQL в Go

Tags: golang, mysql

Добрый день.
Никак не удается подключиться к MySQL из Go, MySQL установлен и запущен. 
Подскажите пожалуйста, чего ему не хватает?

После "гугления" у меня получился вот такой код:

```
package main

import "database/sql"
import _ "code.google.com/p/go-mysql-driver/mysql"

func main() {
    db, err := sql.Open("mysql", "root:123456@/my_db")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    res, err := db.Query("SELECT * FROM `my_table`")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    for res.Next() {

    }

    db.Close()
}
```

При запуске выдает следующее:

```
panic: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:3306: connection refused

goroutine 1 [running]:
main.main()
    /home/username/EclipseProjects/test/src/main.go:14 +0x116

goroutine 2 [syscall]:
created by runtime.main
    /home/username/go/src/pkg/runtime/proc.c:221

goroutine 3 [syscall]:
syscall.Syscall6()
    /home/username/go/src/pkg/syscall/asm_linux_amd64.s:40 +0x5
syscall.EpollWait(0xf800000006, 0xf84008b0c0, 0xa0000000a, 0xffffffff, 0xc, ...)
    /home/username/go/src/pkg/syscall/zerrors_linux_amd64.go:1781 +0xa1
net.(*pollster).WaitFD(0xf84008b0b0, 0xf84003e9c0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, ...)
    /home/username/go/src/pkg/net/fd_linux.go:146 +0x110
net.(*pollServer).Run(0xf84003e9c0, 0x0)
    /home/username/go/src/pkg/net/fd.go:236 +0xe4
created by net.newPollServer
    /home/username/go/src/pkg/net/newpollserver.go:35 +0x382
```

Comment: Попробуйте добавить `?charset=utf8` при открытие соединения. Скорее всего ошибка в настройтке MySql базы. Посмотрите порты, к которым идет соединение.

Comment: Да, поясните параметры подключения к базе и настройки запуска базы.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`tcp 127.0.0.1:3306: connection refused` — дело не в программе, написано же — не слушает сервер там. Вероятно, он на UNIX socket слушает, а не по TCP — пробуйте что-то в духе `"root:123456@unix(/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock)/my_db"`.

Comment: drdaeman
Спасибо большое!
Теперь все работает!